# Calculation of equivalent parameters of a few RL links for direct current circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, inductance

Is there a way to calculate equivalent parameters of a few RL links for direct current circuit (like on the generalized example on the image below)?

So far I've studied that known formulas for series/parallel connections of R and L elements cannot be used because it's not R and L elements, which are connected in parallel and series, but RL elements (as a single entity), which can connected in parallel or series.

[image]

Comment: What you are missing is that neither the resistors alone nor the inductors alone are in parallel - you have one RL and another RL in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

> what am I missing here?

The two inductors are not in parallel, so you can't use the parallel inductors formula to combine them.

Two components are in parallel only if both ends are connected together. In this circuit, only one end of the inductors is connected. The other end is separated by the resistors.

---

If you want to solve this circuit the easy way is to notice that since the source is an ideal voltage source, the current through one branch (with 3.5 ohm and 2 H) does not affect what happens to the other branch (with 7 ohm and 2 H).

So you can simply solve for $i_1$ using the method you already know for solving a simple LR circuit. Then solve for $i_2$ the same way. Then use KCL ($i_0 = i_1 + i_2$) to find the current through the source.

Comment: aha! So, that's how it works. They are not in parallel. Then it makes sense. This very simple example I've chosen because I failed to understand it. It's not my homework, like someone may think. I need to understand to create a simplified simulation of RL circuit for a video game. Though the circuit I want to simulate is even more complicated. But now I see. So far my error is to think the they are in parallel. Thank you!

Comment: After the first moment the L do not play any role so you consider them as 0 resitance, since you talk about DC ,different if you have AC